# Frequency Shift a Bode Magnitude Plot

Tags: delay, bode-plot, frequency-response

for the 2nd order response of $$1-\dfrac{2\zeta\omega s + \omega^{2}}{s^{2}+2\zeta\omega s + \omega^{2}}$$

I get the plot shown in blue.  How do I go about getting the plots shown in red and green that is basically frequency shifted?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term \$\omega\$ (natural resonant frequency) needs to be lowered in value. It should be as simple as that but you may also want to tweak the \$\zeta\$ term to modify the peakiness of the filter.